# How null-coalsescing operator works

Tags: c#, .net, null-coalescing-operator

I got three classes (classA, classB and classC) that inherit from an interface 'IFoo'; if use this

```
var fooItem = (request.classAitem ?? (request.classBitem  as IFoo ?? request.classCitem))
```

or

```
var fooItem = (request.classAitem ?? request.classBitem ?? request.classCitem as IFoo)
```

it works just fine but other combinations won't even compile:

```
var fooItem = (request.classAitem as IFoo ?? request.classBitem ?? request.classCitem)
```

or

```
var fooItem = (request.classAitem ?? request.classBitem ?? request.classCitem) as IFoo
```

It seems to me that in some cases the compiler implicitly unboxes the child classes to their IFoo interface but in some other cases don't. What do you guys think?

Comment: What are the types of `classAitem`, `classBitem` and `classCitem`? Please show the definition of those. Also, what is `ContactPoint`? Does that implement `IFoo`?

Comment: can not compile but with what error ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @poke, I reworked the code samples classAitem, classBItem and classCitem are of type classA, classB and classC and their only relevant feat is that they implement IFoo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both of your examples that don't work, because `??` is right-associative, we're first trying to determine the data type of this expression:

```
request.classBitem ?? request.classCitem
```

The data type can only be the data type of one of its inputs, if the data types are different. There's obviously no conversions available in either direction here and so you get a compiler error. Note that the compiler will *not* decide that the data type here is `IFoo` just because both classes happen to implement it (and if it did, what would happen if they both implemented multiple common interfaces?)

Compare this to your first two examples. In the first, we first consider this expression:

```
request.classBitem  as IFoo ?? request.classCitem
```

The type of this expression is either `IFoo` or whatever the data type of `request.classCitem` is. There's a conversion from the type of `request.classCitem` to `IFoo` and so that's obviously selected and so the entire expression's data type is `IFoo`. That is then used to determine the type of the overall expression (again, `IFoo`).

The second case is very similar, since `??` is right associative<sup>1</sup>, we first have to determine the type of:

```
request.classBitem ?? request.classCitem as IFoo
```

And again, we have a choice between `IFoo` and whatever the data type of `request.classBitem` is. There's a conversion to `IFoo` and so that is chosen.

<sup>1</sup>And note, also, that it means the parentheses in the first example are superfluous.

Comment: I see your point: it evaluates the full expression starting from the right, "var fooItem = (request.classAitem as ContactPoint ?? request.classBitem ?? request.classCitem)" won't work because first thing it does is evaluate "request.classBitem ?? request.classCitem" which is unsolvable because as you said classB and classC could share  any number of interfaces. Great answer.

Comment: @Zalomon - I was being careful to avoid using the word "evaluate" - because it won't *evaluate* `classBitem` or `classCitem` at all, if `classAitem` is not `null`. But what it does need to do is determine the *data type* of the overall expression which does need to consider the data types of all potential inputs.